# Percentage of consumption reduced.

Tags: percentages

The price of sugar has increased by 20%. sneha has decided to only spend 8% more than what she initially did on sugar. By what percentage does she need to reduce her sugar consumption?

Answer (score 0):

Say that the price of sugar had been £1 for 100g. If it increases by 20%, it will now be 100g for £1.20. If Sneha decides to spend 8% more, she is prepared to spend £1.08. It should now be fairly obvious how to finish the problem.

Answer (score 0):

${1\over 1.2}=83 {1\over 3} \%$ Therefore, $$83 {1\over 3}\% \cdot 108\% = 90\%$$ is what can be bought. implying 10% decrease.